# Android app bundle and dynamic module delivery

Tags: google-play-console, android-app-bundle

Does the app gets reinstalled when a change is done in dynamic module but not in base.
Example:- 2 users have installed the application and out of which one has just the base apk and the other has base as well as the dynamic module which he has installed after downloading the application.

Now if there is a bug in the dynamic module and we update it and update the app bundle on google play. Does the app will get reinstalled for the user which does not have the dynamic module installed.

I have tried lot's of docs and have not been able to find few questions. Can anyone help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish an update to your app, even if limited to one dynamic module, you will need to update the versionCode of your app. Thus, all your users will see an update and get the new version, even those who have only the base module installed.

That being said, users who have auto-update enabled (i.e. not updating manually through the Play Store) will receive only a patch between the old version and the new version, which should thus be very small if none of the files in the base module have changed.

Comment: If users update manually from Play Store, they may or may not download the full (albeit compressed) app.